# Install BEST package in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bayesian, pymc3

I am going to use the BEST package (https://best.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in order to perform Bayesian Estimation Supersedes the T-test. This helps statisticians compare and interpret the group differences with uncertainty. However, even after I installed the 'best' package using `!pip install best`, Jupyter Notebook will still return the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'best'` if I type `import best`. I also tried `!conda install best` but after that the console returns another error:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- best

Based on this, is there a way to install the `best` package? I hope somebody could update the documentation for Anaconda users after solving this problem (I mean I can volunteer if I'm granted the opportunity!). At the bottom line, since I'm familiar with PyMC3, I can go with that if the `best` package is still not ready. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I am having the same problem! I tried doing it outside anaconda in just command line python and get the same issue... Please let me know if you find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to the developer Laszlo Treszkai (really nice guy!) and he fixed the issue. Uninstall and re-install and it should work!